# Confirmation dialog appears for every instance of jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of items with a delete icon with Ajax.ActionLink that asks for confirmation for the delete action. The issue was the confirmation dialog appears for each instance of the "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" in the browser for the web application. For example, if the count file instance is 5 then the confirmation dialog appears 5 times which would be annoying the user that would force them to check the option 'Prevent this page from additional dialogs' thus prevents appearance of the confirmation dialog unless the page is refreshed. I have also tried to load the file only once (in the login page) using the bundle option which was working as expected but the 'jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js' does not load if the user closes the browser without logging-out and revisits the web app. This causes HTTP 404 error with HTTP GET request being sent to the controller instead of HTTP POST as the file is not loaded when the delete icon is clicked.
[Screen shot for the JavaScript confirm dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm6BD.png)

Here is my code snippet for the Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyNameSpace.Models.FileDownloadModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.BlobFileName</td>
        <td>@(String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.00}", item.BlobLength / 1024))</td>
        <td>@item.BlobContentType</td>
        <td>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteFile", new { blobFileName = item.BlobFileName, contName = item.ContainerName }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Are you sure, you would like to delete the file?", HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" }, new { @class = "ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline", @title = "Delete" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The questions are:
1. Is there a way to load the JavaScript file if it is not already present?

2. Is there a way to prevent the file being loaded more than once?

I would appreciate any suggestions from the wizards.
Thanks, R.

Update:
I'm sorry, I should have posted the code for the parent view along with the partial view.

Code Snippet for the Parent View:

```
 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Title_of_Page";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSignedIn.cshtml";
 } 
 <div id="secFiles">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/path/partialView.cshtml", Model);}
</div>
 @section Scripts {
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function OnSuccess(data) { 
           //code to refresh the list after delete action 
           if (data) {
             $('#secFiles').html(data).enhanceWithin();
           }
      }
 </script>
 }
```

Comment: It sounds like your problem is that in whatever partial view is displaying something (maybe the Ajax Action Link?) is each including a reference to the JavaScript file? You need to include it on the main page, and not within a partial view that gets added multiple times to the page.

Comment: The reference for the JavaScript file indeed was in the main page and that  too inside the body of the layout to ensure the file is loaded. I have similar action in three different web pages of the Web App. Resolving this issue would be really helpful.

Comment: So you just need it the once in the main file. You don't need to include it inside the partial views to be able to reference the DOM objects inside the partial view.

Comment: I have even tried with @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mslibajax") in the header of the _layoutSignedIn.cshtml (layout file after signing in) with bundle config as bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mslibajax").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")); but with no luck.